# Cloning only some parts of an HTML element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm cloning a list element in this way:

```
$('ol li.menu-item').click(function() {
  $(this).clone().appendTo('#check-items');
});
```

The `li.menu-item` has a `span.name` element. I would like to copy just that element to `#check-items` (I have many li.menu-items). Any suggestions to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('ol li.menu-item').click(function() {
  $(this).find('span.name').clone().appendTo('#check-items');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could provide `this` as context to the selector.

```
$('ol li.menu-item').click(function() {
  $('span.name', this).clone().appendTo('#check-items');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('ol li.menu-item').click(function() {
    $('#check-items').append($('span.name', this).html());
});
```